# How to compare month and year in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

i need to compare date.like input date is greater than current next month.using normal date in JavaScript.

```
  //comparison_date is date which is current date + one month
  // 14/07/2022 + One Month
    input_date : 14/07/2022
    comparison_date : 14/08/2022
    if(input_date> comparison_date){
    // false
    }


    input_date : 14/08/2022
    comparison_date : 14/08/2022
    if(input_date> comparison_date){
    // false
    }

    input_date : 14/09/2022
    comparison_date : 14/08/2022
    if(input_date> comparison_date){
    // true
    }

    input_date : 22/12/2022
    comparison_date : 14/01/2023
    if(input_date> comparison_date){
    // false
    }
```

Comment: It looks like the following question has already bunch of information how to achieve that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript?rq=1

Comment: how to achieve by comparing with input_data > current date + one month.

Comment: here i am not comparing text..i just shown it for reference

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```js
const toDate = dateString => {
   const [day, month, year] = dateString.split('/')
   return new Date(`${year}-${month}-01 00:00:00`)
}



console.log(toDate('14/07/2022') > toDate('14/08/2022'))
console.log(toDate('14/08/2022') > toDate('14/08/2022'))
console.log(toDate('14/09/2022') > toDate('14/08/2022'))
console.log(toDate('22/12/2022') > toDate('14/01/2023'))
```

if you just need to compare year and month you can also do something more simple  like this

```js
const toYearMonth = stringDate => {
  const [_, month, year] = stringDate.split('/')
  
  return Number(`${year}${month}`)
}

console.log(toYearMonth('14/07/2022') > toYearMonth('14/08/2022'))
console.log(toYearMonth('14/08/2022') > toYearMonth('14/08/2022'))
console.log(toYearMonth('14/09/2022') > toYearMonth('14/08/2022'))
console.log(toYearMonth('22/12/2022') > toYearMonth('14/01/2023'))
```

Comment: you get funny behaviour comparing the date objects directly best to get the underlying timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Text doesn't compare datewise, you need to convert to a timestamp and compare the values, the Date class would do this for you

```
const date1 = new Date("2022-07-14");
const date2 = new Date("2022-08-14");
console.log(date1.getTime() > date2.getTime());
console.log(date1.getTime() => date2.getTime());
console.log(date1.getTime() < date2.getTime());
console.log(date1.getTime() >= date2.getTime());
console.log(date1.getTime() == date2.getTime());
```

assuming you want the current date + one month you can do

```
current = new Date();
nextMonth = current.setMonth(current.getMonth()+1);//note this changes the value of "current"
```

however depending on the type of compare you want you may need to customise the compare, ie date one is midnight case 2 is midnight and a microsecond is this greater than or equal? depends on your situation

note: you appear to be using the en-GB date format which is a pain try to use ISO yyyy-mm-dd, it simplifies many things